# fields.E305 reverse query name clashes with reverse query name

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to have audit columns in each model. However, once two models have the same code, I get an error "(fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'app.Model.created_on' clashes with the reverse query name for 'app.Model.created_on'.

- created_on
- created_by
- updated_on
- updated_by

Example

```py
class ModelB(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='created_by', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='updated_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='created_by', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='updated_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I don't really need a reverse key in users for each of these, but I want a way to be able to lookup the user_id if necessary.

Comment: Why do you make two `class ModelB`s? This does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: It was more of an example. Let's say I want all database changes made to any model audited, I would have a created_on, created_by, updated_on, and updated_by field for each model. I also learned that I can simply add related_name='+' to prevent the reverse being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue with the following.

```py
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='created_by_%(class)s_related', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='updated_by_%(class)s_related', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Reference [Multiple foreign key fields in abstract Django class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672180/multiple-foreign-key-fields-in-abstract-django-class)